# WPF application not working with Visual studio ClickOnce

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, clickonce

My WPF application, which is published through ClickOnce in Visual Studio, but the application is started with administrator privileges to provide the function of manually checking for updates.

But it doesn't work with administrator rights.

Here's the code for admin startup:

```
private void CheckAdministrator()
{
    var wi = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    var wp = new WindowsPrincipal(wi);
    bool runAsAdmin = wp.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
    if (!runAsAdmin)
    {
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
        {
            UseShellExecute = true,
            Verb = "runas",
            Arguments = StartFlag
        };
        try
        {
            Process.Start(processInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {}
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

What is the solution? Is there something wrong with my update strategy?

Comment: The ClickOnce application itself cannot be run with administrative privileges. The user may be able to start another process with administrative privileges depending on the user's permissions.

Comment: Checking and installing updates is a built-in feature of ClickOnce.  Don't help.

Comment: Please feel free to let know if you have any question.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is indeed the case, it seems that I have some worries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must run ClickOnce application with administrator privileges, you need to first determine whether the current one is administrator privileges, and you need to add the following code at the project entry point:

```
    private bool AdminFlag()
    {
        var a = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        var b = new WindowsPrincipal(a);

        return b.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
    }

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!AdminFlag())
        {
            var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);

            processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            processInfo.Verb = "runas";

            try
            {
                Process.Start(processInfo);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please run with administrator privileges");
            }

            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
        else
        {
            //do what you want
        }
    }
```

Of course, as Hans Passant said, checking for and installing updates is a built-in feature of ClickOnce. none of these things you need to worry about